# Проверка регулярным выражением на букву любого языка

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Народ, у кого есть на регулярнных выражения проверка на любую букву на любом языке?

Comment: Не совсем ясно, вам нужно отловить какую-то букву определенную или наоборот вам нужно отловить, чтобы всё, кроме букв.

Answer (score 2):

**(int)$id;** - даже, если после первого числа будут любые символы и цифры, то они "отсекаются"

```
$id = '15-W_T_F?+100500';
echo (int)$id; // результат - 15
//но
$id = 'W_T_F?+100500';
echo (int)$id; // результат - 0
```

Можно конечно и регулярку, но если есть вариант обойтись без неё, то не используйте.

```
echo preg_replace('/([^\d]+)[^\D]+/i','',$id); // результат - 15
```

Comment: Ищем всё, что не есть цифрой:

    if(preg_match('/[^\d]+/i',$id)){
        echo "Кроме цифр, еще что-то есть";
    } else {
        echo "Букаф ёк";
    }